# How to load this Clojure project in my cider REPL? Why I am receiving the message "The clojure executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path’" (NixOS)?

Tags: clojure, executable, leiningen, nixos, cider

Recently, I started learning Clojure. I have been using Emacs, and cider (REPL). Also, I have NixOS as OS.

I have been able to successfully program in Clojure using this environment. Usually, I create the files, then I go to the directory where the `.clj` are, I execute `cider-jack-in`, a REPL is created, and interactive programming magic happens. Thus, I am able to load the file, load new versions of old functions, etc.

It also works if I just start Emacs and execute `cider-jack-in. The mini-buffer asks:

> Are you sure you want to run `cider-jack-in' without a Clojure project? (y or n)

After answering `y`, everything works fine.

While reading the book *Clojure for the Brave and True*, I have also successfully used:

```lisp
$ lein run
```

For learning purposes, I decided to explore some open source projects. Thus, I did a `git clone` of this open-source [project](https://github.com/collbox/http-cron).

Being on the folder, I decided to reproduce the steps that have worked so far. However, it does **not** work. After executing `cider-jack-in`, the mini-buffer echoes the following:

```lisp
The clojure executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path
```

Also, if I try with `lein` I get:

```sh
[pedro@system:~/projects/http-cron]$ lein run
No :main namespace specified in project.clj.
```

Obs.: If I type `clojure` on the shell, this is what I get:

```lisp
[pedro@system:~]$ clojure
The program 'clojure' is not in your PATH. You can make it available in an
ephemeral shell by typing:
  nix-shell -p clojure
```

Why is this happening?

How can I solve this (considering that I am using NixOS)?

Comment: Can you try typing `clojure` at your shell and seeing if that brings up anything?  Seems like `clojure` is not in your `PATH`.  You will need to remedy that first.  `lein` is not likely to work since the http-cron project has no `project.clj`.

Comment: Indeed, @dorab. This is what I get: `[pedro@system:~]$ clojure
The program 'clojure' is not in your PATH. You can make it available in an
ephemeral shell by typing:
  nix-shell -p clojure`

What should I do to fix it?  Just doing `nix-shell -p clojure` is going to be temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going the imperative route, depending on whether you use NixOS with channels (default) or flakes, you can permanently install `clojure` into your environment with:

- channels: `nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -iA clojure`
- flakes: `nix profile install nixpkgs#clojure`

The preferred (declarative) way would however be adding `clojure` to `environment.systemPackages` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and running `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`.